# Tyring to find a new way to have tool durability work for custom tools in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. Anyone have any ideas?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Now that the "on_dig", as well as "on_hurt_entity" and possibly even "on_tool_used", have been removed as of 1.20.20 and 1.20.40, the custom tools that I am making do not lose durability when mining any kind of block, no matter if it is listed within "minecraft:digger".  The only time the tools lose durability is when used to attack a mob.

I found another similar question related to my issue on here where someone suggested using a script that they provided, but even this doesn't work.

Link to the other question: [Item component "on_dig" has been removed - How to handle tool durability in new Minecraft Bedrock addons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405592/item-component-on-dig-has-been-removed-how-to-handle-tool-durability-in-new)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! We prefer updated answers to existing threads over opening new ones with the same premise, but as a new user this is naturally not very obvious. I'll vote to close this as a duplicate, but upvoted it for your effort. I'll look into offering a bounty on the other question tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, SGETiminator! Have you tried updating the version number for `@minecraft/server` to **1.9.0-beta**? It should work again after that. If not, or if you're not sure how to set up the manifest.json file to include the server module as a dependency, let me know and I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but do you have Content Logs enabled? You can check under Settings --> Creator --> "Enable Content Log File" and "Enable Content Log GUI." If both toggles are on, you may get a more specific error message if something in your addon isn't working. I've found this to be very helpful when writing script files, along with `console.warn()` for debugging (the regular console.log() function doesn't work in this environment). If the message disappears before you can read it, you can see it again under "Content Log History" in the same place.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I will change the @minecraft/server as you suggested and see if that fixes it.  Thank you for replying very quickly, I didn't expect to get anything and thought that my project was just dead.  Would you happen to know if I will need to change either the @minecraft/server-gametest or the @minecraft/server-ui?  They are both currently set to 1.0.0-beta...

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using Bridge to create my addon.  Also if you could I would appreciate if you explain how to set the manifest.json to include the server module as a dependency.  I mentioned that I use Bridge just in case it already does that for me...

Comment: @SGETiminator I have never used Bridge, or either of the two other modules you mention. The documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server-ui/minecraft-server-ui?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable#changelog says the current beta version for `@minecraft/server-ui` is **1.2.0-beta**, so I'd assume you'd have to use that. For `@minecraft/server-gametest`, this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server-gametest/minecraft-server-gametest?view=minecraft-bedrock-experimental says it's still using **1.0.0-beta**.

Comment: I will add the manifest file to my answer on the other (linked) question.

Comment: While I don't have the experience to help you with Bridge-related stuff, if you're still having issues with your project after updating the manifest.json file, I can send you a working addon template with *only* the custom tool functionality. This might help with debugging - otherwise, I would recommend asking a separate question here (tagged with [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition] and [tag:minecraft-addons]) specifically about integrating Bridge into a pack which uses the latest beta versions.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck It would be awesome if you could send me that template, that way it could at the very least make sure I'm doing everything right.  I am just now diving into the world of creating things like this for Minecraft and I have to say its very intimidating lol.  Thank you for all the help you have provided so far.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9dlf2gvg17pjr8q/CustomTools.zip/file For the template, I have the custom tools made from copper to keep it as simple as possible, but you could also use any custom block or item. To try out the tool functionality, I would recommend first creating a new world with the Beta Server APIs toggle enabled, then, after the world has been loaded, choose "Edit World" and activate the behavior pack from that menu. (This avoids a bug where the inventory tabs don't render if a new world is created with an addon active.)

Comment: The resource pack should be automatically activated when you add the behavior pack to your world. Here is a link to the instructions for how to add the pack to your Minecraft development folders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/gettingstarted?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable&tabs=Windows10

Comment: Let me know if it's working for you -- I've tested it on Windows 11 Bedrock Edition and haven't found any issues.

Comment: I'm fairly new to addon development, too! When I first got started, I was pretty much stuck whenever something had changed from the last version in the documentation. But, after doing some experimenting and also combining bits and pieces from different tutorials, it's starting to be a lot more fun :) Besides the official documentation at Microsoft Learn, I've found that the Bedrock Wiki site is very helpful: https://wiki.bedrock.dev/ as well as the Minecraft Wiki for comparing to vanilla features: https://minecraft.wiki/

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Thank you for everything!!!!  Making the server module a dependency did the trick.  I will also be sure to check out your template so that I can learn more.  Once again thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SGETiminator The Minecraft update which was just released today broke the old version of the pack, so if you're experiencing issues again, that's why. I have updated it (new link: https://www.planetminecraft.com/texture-pack/custom-tools-template-full-functionality-requires-beta-apis-toggle/) to be compatible with the latest version, as well as fix some other minor issues the old version had.